# Y-axis Labels Missing?

Tags: r, plot

the plot I am working on works fine but for some reason, the Y-Axis label is not showing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Europe <- subset(data, continent == "Europe")
Americas<- subset(data, continent == "Americas")
Asia <- subset(data, continent == "Asia")

counts_europe <- table(Europe$decade)
counts_americas <- table(Americas$decade)
counts_asia <- table(Asia$decade)

plot(names(counts_europe), counts_europe , col = "blue", type = "l",
main = "Number of Assassinations by Decade", xlab = "Decade",
ylab = "Number of Assassinations", xlim = c(1875, 2005))

lines(names(counts_americas), counts_americas, col = "red", type = "l")
lines(names(counts_asia), counts_asia , col = "green", type = "l")

text(1935, 13, "Europe")
text(1935, 8, "Americas")
text(1935, 5, "Asia")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very weird situation, basically, you have on the x variable a `character` and y variable a `table`, so I think the plot function got confused. So for example:

```
set.seed(100)
counts_europe = table(sample(1880:1980,200,replace=TRUE))
class(names(counts_europe))
[1] "character"
plot(names(counts_europe),counts_europe,type="l")
```

[image]

You need to make both of them numeric, one way is below:

```
res = cbind(year=as.numeric(names(counts_europe)),counts_europe)
plot(res,type="l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab, since we don't have your data.

Up front, Y axis labels/ticks are generally automatic.

For most of `par` options, you can also enable them within the call to `plot` and get the effects temporarily for that instance of `plot`. That's true here:

```r
plot(1:3, 2:4, type='l', main='Quux', yaxt = 'n')
```

[image: basic plot, no y-ticks]

However, as it is temporary, a subsequent call to `plot` without `yaxt` does not carry forward that option.

For many, however, including those extra 8 characters (10+ with spaces, comma) is onerous, so we have the ability to set that option as the default for all subsequent plots *on that particular graphics device*:

```r
par(yaxt = "n")
# any number of other plotting things going on here
plot(1:3, 2:4, type='l', main='Quux')
```

(Same plot, no y-axis ticks.)

There are two approaches to fixing this:

1. Manually reset the option with `par(yaxt = "s")` (its default value). This has the unfortunate property that it resets only that parameters ... since you already know you have one stale option, it's possible you have others that you don't know about.
2. Close the graphics device and start over. This is easily done with `dev.off`, though please ensure you are closing the correct device (I occasionally have multiple graphics open, and have closed the wrong one ...).

   In base R (where a new window appears for each plot device), it is visible in the window title, as in

   [image: R graphic device window]

   and is confirmed programmatically on the console with:

   ```r
   dev.list()
   # windows 
   #       2 
   dev.off(2)
   ```

   RStudio is not that different, and though there is no device number in its UI, one can find:

   ```r
   dev.list()
   # RStudioGD       png 
   #         2         3 
   dev.off(2)
   ```

   When you call `dev.off(2)`, the graphics pane in the UI will go blank, after which a subsequent plot will bring it back to its original state (hopefully, with `yaxt` returned to its default value along with any other values that may have changed).